# Angular modules - shared module that uses 3rd party package/modules

Tags: angular

**Setup**

1. I have a lot of lazy loaded modules
2. I have a 3rd party module that defines its components/directives
3. I need to use 3rd party component in many modules (eager and lazy loaded ones)
4. 3rd party module has its config called like `3PModule.forRoot({someConfig: someValue})`

I'd like to have a single point in my app where i import `3PModule` with the config and use it that way in any of my app modules.

**Problems/questions**

1. If i import it only in `AppModule` - it doesn't work in my lazy loaded modules. (template error, directive unknown)

   [This one should be because, in my understanding, `AppModule` does
   import `SharedModule` but since `SharedModule` is not the one having
   particular components/directives in its `declarations`, then
   `AppModule` does not have definitions for those 3rd party
   components/declarations. Is this correct?
   UPDATE: actually, this might be because modules are not hierarchical so each module has to import `SharedModule` separately]
2. If i import it only in some `SharedModule` then i'm not sure how to export it with configuration: `3PModule.forRoot({someConfig: someValue})`

What is the proper solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

I think you will have to import `3PModule.forRoot({someConfig: someValue})` in your `AppModule` and also import `3PModule` in your `SharedModule` and export it from there. The reason is for this because `forRoot` registers all the providers so that needs to be done only once (by importing it in core or AppModule) but to use the respective directives or components you will have to just import that module in the respective Modules that you want to use so its better to import it in `SharedModule` and export it from there as `SharedModule` is import all the modules.